# How do I update useState immidiatly for function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a function to calculate the winner between the two selected pokemon. However, instead of using the newly selected option, it is using the previously selected option. It has been brought to my attention that this is because useState is not updating immediately so  how would I go about fixing this?

Here is my winner function:

```
function selectedWinner(){

console.log(pokemonName+' '+pokeOneTotal);
console.log(pokemonName2+' '+pokeTwoTotal);
if(pokeOneTotal>pokeTwoTotal){
    setPokemonWinner(pokemonName);
}else if(pokeOneTotal<pokeTwoTotal){
    setPokemonWinner(pokemonName2);
}else{
    setPokemonWinner("Draw");
}
```

}

I have set it so that it is called in the different select functions, which are on click functions, here is one as an example:

```
 function optionOneSelected(){
   
    console.log('selected');
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+ pokemonOne.current.value)
    .then((res)=>{

      let data=res.data;
      console.log(data);

      let type = data.types[0].type.name;
      let id = data.id;
      let height= data.height;
      let weight = data.weight;
      let name = data.forms[0].name;
      let hp = data.stats[0].base_stat;

      //console.log(type)

      setPokemonType(type);
      setPokemonId(id);
      setPokemonHeight(height);
      setPokemonWeight(weight);
      setPokemonName(name);
      setPokemonHp(hp);

        let sum=0;
        sum= data.stats[0].base_stat+ data.stats[1].base_stat+ data.stats[2].base_stat+ data.stats[3].base_stat+data.stats[4].base_stat+data.stats[5].base_stat;
        setPokeOneTotal(sum);


          let pokemonOneDataList = [
            data.stats[0].base_stat, data.stats[1].base_stat, data.stats[2].base_stat, data.stats[3].base_stat,data.stats[4].base_stat,data.stats[5].base_stat
          ];

          let labels = [
              'hp', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Special Attack', 'Special Defense', 'Speed'
          ];

          setPokemonOneData(pokemonOneDataList);
          setDataLabels(labels);
          selectedWinner();
          
      


    })
```

}

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with `pokeOneTotal` and `pokeTwoTotal` as dependencies. Whenever `pokeOneTotal` or `pokeTwoTotal` updates, it will trigger `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(pokeOneTotal>pokeTwoTotal){
       setPokemonWinner(pokemonName);
   }else if(pokeOneTotal<pokeTwoTotal){
       setPokemonWinner(pokemonName2);
   }else{
       setPokemonWinner("Draw");
   }
}, [pokeOneTotal, pokeTwoTotal])
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // Whatever we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [state])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "state" in the example is interchangeable with whatever state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Pass the new values to `selectedWinner` as arguments instead of reading from the state.
- Move the call to `selectedWinner` into a separate `useEffect` hook that has those state variables as dependencies (so it gets called when, and only when, any of them change).